# What plugin is this

Tags: php, wordpress, joomla

Please can one of you Wordpress or PHP gurus tell me what plugin this site is using for the photo albums - I desperately need one just like this - **with password protection**.  I actually want it for a Joomla site, but figured if I can find out what this one is, I might be able to mod it to work with Joomla.

www.photobooth.co.uk/albums

Thanks in advance for any help.

Rob.

Comment: cazy idea - ask them

Comment: They're my main competitor so I don't think they'd answer me

Comment: I'm not sure its actually a WordPress plugin given the structure of the files.  This [google search](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22Enter+Your+Event+ID+to+View%22) reveals a number of other sites using it.  May be able to ask one of them.

Comment: Your mentioned website is not using WordPress :)

Answer (score 1):

The two plugins I have detected on this website are 'Ultimate Social Media and Share Icons (Twitter, Facebook, Google+, Instagram, Pinterest etc.)' and 'MailChimp for WP'.

That would lead me to believe that it is most likely built into the theme, whatever that page is using.  The theme is ePhoto, found [here](http://www.elegantthemes.com/gallery/ephoto/) but it also looks like eGallery found [here](http://www.elegantthemes.com/gallery/egallery/).

Source: http://www.wpthemedetector.com/